# Avoid passing second param to every unit test using mock.patch

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm mocking my `RpcClient` class for all of my unit tests like this:

```
import unittest2
from mock import patch

@patch('listeners.RpcClient')
class SomeTestCase(unittest2.TestCase):

    test_something(self, mock_api):
        ...

    test_something_else(self, mock_api):
        ...
```

For most of my tests I don't want to do any assertions using the mock object, all I want to do is patch the class so the `RpcClient` doesn't attempt to connect and fire requests for each of my tests (I have it hooked up to a post save event on one of my models).

**Can I avoid passing in `mock_api` into every single one of my tests?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing the mocking in `setUp` using `patcher.start()`:

```
def setUp(self):
    self.rpc_patcher = patch('listeners.RpcClient')
    self.MockClass = rpc_patcher.start()

def tearDown(self):
    self.rpc_patcher.stop()
```

So I don't have to decorate any of my test cases and don't have to add any extra arguments to my tests.

More info:

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock#patch-methods-start-and-stop

Answer (score 0):

Can you just set a default parameter to mock_api?

```
def test_something(self, mock_api=None):
    ...

def test_something_else(self, mock_api=None):
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use `mock.patch` as a context manager for when you call the SUT. Something like:

```
import unittest2
from mock import patch


class SomeTestCase(unittest2.TestCase):

    def call_sut(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with mock.patch('listeners.RpcClient'):
            # call SUT

    def test_something(self):
        self.call_sut()
        # make assertions

    def test_something_else(self):
        self.call_sut()
        # make assertions
```